# IntelliJ IDEA micronaut-openapi javac annotation processor searching in IntelliJ directory for openapi.properties

Tags: micronaut-openapi

I'm using the Micronaut OpenAPI module and facing an issue that the default `openapi.properties` is not correctly processed in IntelliJ. Doing the compilation on the command line works. When analyzing the annotation module I found that it is looking in the IntelliJ related directory `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\compile-server` directory for it, where it is obviously not found. This prevents to use the configuration options from the `openapi.properties`. It seems to be not possible to configure IntelliJ to use the project directory as working directory for the annotation processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micronaut offers the system property configuration option `micronaut.openapi.config.file`. This can be passed to the annotation processor as system variable using the `pom.xml` file. IntelliJ will pick up this.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
       ...
       <path>
         <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
          <artifactId>micronaut-openapi</artifactId>
          <version>use most recent version</version>
       </path>
  </annotationProcessorPaths>
  <compilerArgs>
    ...
    <arg>-Amicronaut.openapi.config.file=${project.basedir}/openapi.properties</arg>
    ...
  </compilerArgs>
  ...
```

For a Gradle based project a similar mechanism should be possible.